# Is replying to an uncertainty correct English?

Tags: spoken-english

Person 1: "I don't know whether to get A or B"

Person 2: "B"

For example:

Person 1: "I don't know whether to get an apple or a windows computer"

Person 2: "windows computer"

As if person 2 is saying, "I think you should get a windows computer".

Would this be considered a "correct" response?

Comment: Please indicate the research you have done. Why do you think it's wrong? It's perfectly reasonable to say "Windows computer". If someone says "I don't know whether to..." it is likely that they are expecting someone to provide advice, give an opinion, or otherwise help - are you expecting them to sit in silence? What response would you consider correct?

Comment: No, if someone is uncertain, you must never reply; you must leave them in their confusion forever.

Answer (score 1):

It would sound rather abrupt and informal to answer with a single word.

"I'd recommend Windows" or "Well, personally I prefer Windows" would be more natural responses. (Note that brand names count as proper nouns and take a capital letter.)

Comment: I don't think it's abrupt. It might be helpful to also give a reason ("I don't know whether to get an apple or a windows computer." "Windows. The games are much better."), but this sort of advice on how to hold a conversation is far off-topic for ELU.

Comment: @StuartF - Well, I meant that it would sound abrupt unless you knew the other person well enough for a one-word answer not to seem rude.